# Capybara unable to find field (text entry) that is/is not disabled

Tags: ruby, capybara

Using Capybara with Cucumber (and Selenium) I am seeing two distinctly different responses that are contradicting themselves and I am a bit lost.

trying to:

`find_field('SANDBOX_FIELD_USERNAME', {disabled: true}).set(username)`

If disabled is set to true then I get

`Unable to find field "SANDBOX_FIELD_USERNAME" that is disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

But if disabled is set to false I get

`Unable to find field "SANDBOX_FIELD_USERNAME" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

I have looked around but can't find anyone else describing this issue so i am sure it must be something i am missing but can anyone shed some light on how this might have occurred?

Comment: Those aren’t contradictory - it can’t find that field at all on the page (disabled or not) - What is the HTML you’re attempting to match

Comment: <input type="email" required="" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="" data-test-id="SANDBOX_FIELD_USERNAME"><br>

<input type="password" required="" name="password" placeholder="Password" data-test-id="SANDBOX_FIELD_PASSWORD"><br>

I have a test previous to this that checks for the element using `expect(page).to have_entry_field` defined in my Page Object and that is passing so I assumed that the field was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capybaras `find_field` finds form fields by id, name, placeholder, or associated label text.  Since "SANDBOX_FIELD_USERNAME" is none of those in the element you're attempting to fill in it doesn't find the field.  You could do

```
fill_in('Username', with: username)
```

to match on the placeholder text, and set the value which is basically the same as

```
find_field('Username').set(username)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this:

```
page.fill_in :placeholder => 'Username', with: 'some_name'
```